# Visual Studio 2022 Preview "MEF Service Broker Package" package not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I installed VS2022, [but getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ437.png)

I tried solutions like deleting the ComponentModelCahce folder, or 'devenv /updateconfiguration' and 'devenv.exe /clearcache', but not worked.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I have same problem. Does it cause any problem while developing?

Comment: I encountered same issue after latest update. Any solution?

Comment: I have reinstalled whole VS and it helped.

Comment: even reinstalling the while visual studio doesnt work for me. having same issue tried deleting `ComponentModelCahce` also

Answer (score 0):

I've just had identical issue, i.e. different messages like the below one were popping-up:

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectPackage' package did not load correctly.

ActivityLog.xml showed the following message:

> SetSite failed for package [MEF Service Broker Package]Source:
> 'mscorlib' Description: Illegal characters in
> path.
> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in
> path.
>    at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String
> path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>
> at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
> maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>    at
> System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
>    at
> System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Init(String path, Boolean
> checkHost)

The following steps helped me:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio
2. Restart Windows
3. Remove `C:\Users\(your_username)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio`
4. Remove `C:\Users\(your_username)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Visual Studio`
5. Install Visual Studio